# Tesseract card reader for iOS 7

Tags: ios7, ocr, tesseract

Is anyway that I could use tesseract gali8 version to read credit cards or ID cards? I have been trying to do it. But I couldn´t get the exact data from the card. I have to make any change of the example xcode program?